# Ecoacoustics: Market Size and Major Private Players

Tags: soundscape, sound, literature, conservation, ecoacoustics

Is there any literature or market report that summarizes the business opportunity for ecoacoustics as a field. Who are the major private tech companies who have solutions in this domain and what is global market size?

Want to be clear that I'm asking for ecoacoustics (and NOT the broader bioacoustics term).

The best I could find by googling was a review paper titled "Conservation acoustics: Animal sounds, audible natures, cheap nature" (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.geoforum.2021.04.022). This paper indicates efforts of google and Microsoft in this area but falls short of indicating a potential market size of ecoacoustics alone.

Comment: I'm confused on the 'agenda' behind this question that is conveyed by the terms "private tech companies" and "global market size".  Could you elaborate, why you consider ecology as a market, or do I misinterpret your Q?

Comment: I don't think there is any sort of agenda here and think this is a very useful question for the world of bioacoustics outside of academia.